# Secondary Jar version don't sync up when deploying

Tags: gradle, publish, artifactory

I'm using gradle artifactory plugin to deploy my library to `oss-snapshot-local`.
The first deploy works as intended and the filenames are correct:
eg.

`skrypton-api-1.0.0-20171014.053125-1-sources.jar`

`skrypton-api-1.0.0-20171014.053125-1.jar`

But on the second deploy, the sources jar is not uploaded despite the plugin saying it has deployed it. I end up with only

`skrypton-api-1.0.0-20171014.053349-2.jar`

Deploying for the third time,

`skrypton-api-1.0.0-20171014.053349-2-sources.jar` shows up. But not third source jar. Only `skrypton-api-1.0.0-20171014.054252-3.jar`

[This is what it looks like in general after 3 deploys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5Bkv.png)

The source jar version seems to be stuck at (deploy number - 1) after the first deployment. Tried it with a javadoc jar and it also doesn't work properly.

[This is the build script in question.](https://github.com/waicool20/SKrypton/blob/master/build.gradle)

Comment: Can you verify that the sources file exist in your work folder? Meaning that the file actually exists on your hard drive after the build run. Also, have you tried running your build in debug mode to check if there is an issue with the script? (can be done by adding '-d' or '--debug' to your build run command)

Comment: Yeah it's there and I've turned on verbose mode, artifactory plugin still says deployment successful, thing is that it only happens on the snapshots repo, if i try publishing on bintray, everything is updated correctly. So now I'm starting to think it's a bug with the plugin.

Comment: Can you add the output of 2 runs that you did with the build, one after the other to the question. Also, what are you seeing in the artifactory.log + request.log?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me, I have the two logs on first and second publish right over here: https://gist.github.com/waicool20/3e146167ac66045bdf9f20ea6dc0b430

Also where are the artifactory.log + request.log files?